# Choosing the Best Data Types and Lengths for Data Mart

Tags: database, ssis, data-warehouse

I am in the process of developing a data mart for one of my clients.

I would like to know if there is any best practice in defining and choosing data types and lengths for the columns in the data mart. I am bit concerned about this as data is going to come from several sources, and the maximum length (according to sql data profiler) is not the maximum in the other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things I'd suggest @picmate ... (We use MS SQL Server (so my data type examples will be from here))

- use integer surrogate keys (small/tiny int if you **know** the number of values in your dimension).
- by implication, dont use natural keys to join dims/facts.
- obviously you will need to choose the longest/largest values are being the ones you build the schema for.
- Don't build for the exact tolerance of fields you expect. e.g. if you are told by the business that product code is CHAR(10) and will never change, make sure you add a few extra characters, as there will always be exceptions that haven't been considered (like a business merger!). So choose VARCHAR(255) instead of CHAR(10). The overhead is only +2 bytes over the length of the variable
- use any native data types that give you a storage advantage (SMALLDATETIME, TIME)

Comment: Hi @Marcus, thanks for the information on having more room than the exact ones which are there in the source. I will use additional spaces then, for all the available fields (where appropriate). By the way, why not use varchar(max) instead of varchar(255)? (just for information)

Comment: @picmate, I guess the varchar(255) for a "short" field is to still give an idea of the size, but varchar(max) is a fair choice too.